# I can't seem to implement this github project as a library

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-studio-import

I fairly new to android studio and I've been trying to implement this [github project](https://github.com/pkleczko/CustomGauge) as a library by creating a directory called libraries and copying the CustomGauge folder to it. Then updating the settings.gradle and dependencies section of the app. Then I added the specified code to content_main and get the following [errors](http://snag.gy/pzAN2.jpg).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

File >> New >> Import Module and load library project , it will be import to your project as a module, and will be add one gradle file under Gradle Scripts.

Sync project with Gradle Files and you are good to go.I hope it will be Ok for you. I tested on Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5
[image]

Comment: I imported as a module and the sync with gradle seemed to be successful, however how do I actually get the custom gauge graphic to show in the design tab, I tried adding the example code from the github page to my content_main but I still get [errors](http://snag.gy/t0kRE.jpg). Apologies I am still relatively new to app development.